# Jersey unit testing with annotation

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jersey

I am working on a Restful Web Service, which get request from client, then strip some information and insert it into the database.

When it insert to the database, it has two parts of information needed: Uri and HttpRequest.

Now I have my method like this:

```
public void insertDb (@Context UriInfo uriInfo, @Context HttpServletRequest request)
```

I am trying to do some unit testing, create a client then WebResouce.

I wonder how can I pass in the parameters in unit testing? Or should I change the params in the `insertDb` function?

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard about Jersey Test Framework? http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/test-framework.html

You don't need to change signature of your method, you need to start Jersey somehow (Test Framework can help you with that) and make request to that Resource. Simple sample of this can be seen in helloworld sample, see http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/sun/jersey/samples/helloworld/1.10/helloworld-1.10-project.zip.

Comment: How about if you want to mock a call handler in resource ? Do you know how to inject dependency mocks withing resource ?